# Creating custom queries with React testing-library and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm trying to [create a custom query](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#add-custom-queries) for [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/) in TypeScript? I intend to use this with a React project.

The query simply gets the first `th` cells in the `tbody` of the container:

```
// all-table-headings.ts - contains the custom query

import { buildQueries } from '@testing-library/dom';

const queryAllTableHeadings = (container: HTMLElement): HTMLElement[] =>
  Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('thead th'));

const getMultipleError = () => '...';
const getMissingError = () => 'Could not find any table headings!';

const [
  queryTableHeadings, getAllTableHeadings, getTableHeadings, findAllTableHeadings, findTableHeadings
] = buildQueries(queryAllTableHeadings, getMultipleError, getMissingError);

export {
  queryTableHeadings, getAllTableHeadings, getTableHeadings, findAllTableHeadings, findTableHeadings
};
```

Here the query is added to a custom render function:

```
// index.ts - exports a custom render function

import { queries, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import * as allTableHeadings from './all-table-headings';
import * as allCellsAtRow from './all-cells-at-row';

const customRender = (ui, options = {}) =>
  render(ui, {
    queries: {
      ...queries,
      ...allTableHeadings,
      ...allCellsAtRow
    },
    ...options
  });

export * from '@testing-library/react';
export { customRender as render };
```

Here's a very simple usage example:

```
const TestComponent = () => <div>Test Component</div>;
const { getAllTableHeadings } = render(<PropsTable component={ TestComponent }/>);
const headings = getAllTableHeadings();
```

However TypeScript complains as follows:

> **TS2554: Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0.**

[image: TypeScript error]

**If I ignore the error by adding `// @ts-ignore` I can confirm that the custom query works, it's just TS that's a bit unhappy.**

Is this something that can be fixed by adding a d.ts file, the documentation on Testing Library isn't very clear how to resolve the TypeScript approach of adding custom queries.

Here's my tsconfig.json for reference:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the type definition `@testing-library/dom` always requires `text` as the 1st option (despite allowing to input as `undefined`). However, I'm not to sure if this is still right with your case with a custom query. Apparently, you've done successfully without any issue in case of having no argument specified. (of course `baz() // <=> baz(undefined)`).

Anyway, To answer your question about if there's a way to override the type, so the answer is yes. Here's the way you can achieve the goal:

Create your `types` at the root dir which a custom types for your repo, then add a file like `testing-library.dom.d.ts` with following content:

`types/testing-library.dom.d.ts`

```js
import "@testing-library/dom";

declare module "@testing-library/dom" {
  // This is the function creates the output for each query function
  // we changed `text` to become optional `text?` in `(text?: P, options?: Q, waitForElementOptions?: W) => R`
  export type BoundFunction<T> = T extends (
    attribute: string,
    element: HTMLElement,
    text: infer P,
    options: infer Q
  ) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q) => R
    : T extends (
        a1: any,
        text: infer P,
        options: infer Q,
        waitForElementOptions: infer W
      ) => infer R
    ? (text?: P, options?: Q, waitForElementOptions?: W) => R
    : T extends (a1: any, text: infer P, options: infer Q) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q) => R
    : never;
}
```

Keep in mind, `include` custom files in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  // ...
  "include": [
    "types/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. I feel like this is extremely close to the solution, however, this causes an error `Duplicate identifier 'BoundFunction'` I was snooping around this same BoundFunction yesterday, but I'm not really sure what all the infer + conditionals mean in this definition, my TypeScript isn't that advanced yet. Perhaps I need to investigate extending the existing definition.

Comment: Can you update the answer where the error comes from + the stack trace then?

Comment: I'm not getting much of a stack trace, my IDE is only showing an error: `TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BoundFunction' on the line `.  `get-queries-for-element.d.ts(3, 13): 'BoundFunction' was also declared here.` This file `node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/get-queries-for-element.d.ts` already contains a `BoundFunction` definition.I'm reading up on `infer` and `extends` usage with the conditionals to try an understand this a bit better.

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig.json then?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the original question, right at the bottom. I need to add that this is a Gatsby theme, so it uses `gatsby-plugin-typescript`, the tsconfig.js is purely there for the IDE, Gatsby uses it's own internal configuration as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Another small observation, if I apply your `text?: string` change directly in `get-queries-for-element.d.ts` that does seem to work, but off course we can't be editing stuff in node_modules.

Comment: I've never told you to edit anything in `node_modules`. Did you follow up what I explained above? You need to create a `types` dir at the root dir then include in the tsconfig file

Comment: I know, I was testing that by applying the change directly, to assert whether the compiler error disappears, I simply did it to check if this in fact resolves the problem. The challenge now is to extend BoundFunction.

I'm now trying to create a new `BoundFunctionEx` and then see if I can use it's type in my `customRender` function instead. Something along the lines of `const customRender = (ui, options = {}): BoundFunctionEx => ...`

Comment: I initially created index.d.ts in the root, moving it to `/types` and adding to the tsconfig.json is unfortunately not making a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227706/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-josef-van-niekerk).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and after updating `"@testing-library/dom"` package to the current latest (`^8.17.1`) solved it for me.